# Missing separate error from makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

With this Makefile, I'm not sure why I'm thrown a missing separator error.

```
define foo
$(eval a := $(1))
$(eval b := $(1))
endef

$(call foo,hello)

$(info $(a))
$(info $(b))

all: ;
```

If I however replaces the first eval with this,

```
$(eval a := $(1)) \
```

then the error goes away. `eval` expands to nothing, and it's happy with only one eval inside the `define`. But I'm not sure why it's complaining in this case, nor why the trailing back slash solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define foo
$(eval a := $(1))
$(eval b := $(1))
endef

bar:=$(call foo,hello)

$(info $(a))
$(info $(b))
$(info bar=[$(bar)])

all: ;
```

Running this makefile outputs:

```
$ make -f Makefile.sample
hello
hello
bar=[
]
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

So $(foo) function outputs new line character. It should either output nothing or value should be captured in variable or trapped with $(eval) or $(strip).

`$(eval a := $(1)) \` results in no new line output from $(foo) that is why it fixes the problem.

Alternatives to adding backslashes to your $(foo) are:

#1:

```
define fooBody
$(eval a := $(1))
$(eval b := $(1))
endef
foo = $(strip $(call fooBody,$1,$2))
```

#2

```
define fooBody
$(eval a := $(1))
$(eval b := $(1))
endef
foo = $(eval $(call fooBody,$1,$2))
```

#3

```
$(strip $(call foo,hello))
```

#4

```
$(eval $(call foo,hello))
```

#5

```
.:=$(call foo,hello)
```

My personal choice is #1.

Comment: You don't need the strip or eval if you assign the results to a variable; it's fine for a variable to contain a newline character (indeed, `fooBody` already does...)

Comment: strip and eval are for cases when result of function call is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, this replaces foo not the call of foo.  Hm.  Personally I don't like that: it's confusing.  I get that it allows you to just use `foo`.  Personally I'm not a fan of the entire idiom of adding eval into variables like this; the normal way would be to just put the assignments in `foo` and eval the results of the call.  But maybe in the real makefiles it makes more sense.

Comment: My suggestions are based on precondition not to touch implementation of `foo`. Otherwise it is definitely better to replace multiple `eval`-s in `foo` with a single external one.

Answer (score 1):

The `call` expansion results in a single newline (because, as you say, both the `eval`'s expand to the empty string.  When make tries to parse that, it doesn't understand it and throws this error.

The important thing to understand is that make will break the input into logical lines *before* it tries to run expansion.  So after the expansion is complete, make expects to see a single line of output and it doesn't understand newlines existing in that single line.

Probably this could be handled better, if you wanted to file a bug at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make

*ETA* Actually I checked and this has already been fixed in GNU make 4.2:

```
$ make-4.1
Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.

$ make-4.2
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```